# java returning a clone of an arraylist wrapped in collections.synchronizedlist

Tags: java, list, arraylist, clone, synchronized

I am wondering how I could produce a clone of my array in the following scenario:

```
private List<TestObject> testList = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<TestObject>());
```

....

```
public synchronized List<TestObject> getAllTestObjects(){
    return testList.clone();
    //I have tried casting to List<TestObject>
}
```

It is moaning about clone() being undefined for List. But I am not sure how best to get around it?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the constructor provided by `ArrayList`

```
public synchronized List<TestObject> getAllTestObjects(){
    return new ArrayList<TestObject>(testList);        
}
```

Comment: is the `synchronized` required here?

Comment: Yes because the copy constructor runs a loop over the given list. See my related answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17616858/2071828) - that's for a `Set` but the same logic holds.

Comment: Ist it safe to just synchronize the method execution when copying the list? AFAIK, you should synchronize on the testList itself.

Comment: @erdal.karaca that depends entirely on your program logic and is a topic too broad for a comment.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
private static class TestObject {
}
private TestObject[] objects = new TestObject[10];
private List<TestObject> testList = 
  Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<TestObject>(Arrays.asList(objects)));
```